# XML DTD validation error issue

Tags: xml, validation, dtd

I am getting the below error while vaidating such a simple xml document, am I missing something

XML

```
<person>
    <profession>cryptographer</profession>
</person>
```

DTD

```
<!ELEMENT person (profession)>
<!ELEMENT profession (#PCDATA)>
```

Error:

```
The Markup In The Document Preceding The Root Element Must Be Well-formed.
```

Validator - http://www.xmlvalidation.com/

Please help

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I can reproduce the error you're seeing with this and I'm assuming this is what you're submitting:

```
<!ELEMENT person (profession)>
<!ELEMENT profession (#PCDATA)>
<person>
    <profession>cryptographer</profession>
</person>
```

If I put your DTD in an internal subset in a DOCTYPE declaration (between the `[` and `]`), it validates using that service.

```
<!DOCTYPE person [
<!ELEMENT person (profession)>
<!ELEMENT profession (#PCDATA)>
]>
<person>
    <profession>cryptographer</profession>
</person>
```

### Edit

If you are trying to reference an external DTD, you will still need to add a DOCTYPE declaration to reference the DTD.

Example:

```
<!DOCTYPE person SYSTEM "so.dtd">
<person>
    <profession>cryptographer</profession>
</person>
```

If you submit this, you will be prompted to load the DTD. This is the DTD you would upload/paste:

```
<!ELEMENT person (profession)>
<!ELEMENT profession (#PCDATA)>
```

**NOTE: When you first submit the XML, be sure that you *don't* have "Validate against external XML schema" selected! DTD and Schema are two different things.**

Comment: The DTD was specified an external file content and that's when it was not validating. Just curious why it works when internal DTD subset is used but doesn't when specified as external.

Comment: @zulfi123786 - Please see my edit on using an external DTD. Let me know if that still doesn't work and I'll add screenshots.